# How does the return statement work in this function?

Tags: python, parsing, tensorflow

I am new to Python especially TensorFlow and have been following this tutorial, but I do not understand what exactly is happening in this return statement. I am specifically confused with what "el[3].strip()).split(", ") for el in conversation_chunks" does. The full tutorial is: https://hub.packtpub.com/build-and-train-rnn-chatbot-using-tensorflow/

I am not understanding why it is "el[3].strip and not just el.strip? What does the [3] relate to? I assume not index?

```
import re
def read_conversations(storage_path, storage_dir):
   filename = storage_path + "/" + storage_dir + "/cornell movie-dialogs corpus/movie_conversations.txt"
   with open(filename, "r", encoding="ISO-8859-1") as fh:
       conversations_chunks = [line.split(" +++$+++ ") for line in fh]
   return [re.sub('[[]']', '', el[3].strip()).split(", ") for el in conversations_chunks]
```

The format is: u0 +++$+++ u2 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ [‘L194’, ‘L195’, ‘L196’, ‘L197’]. The tutorial says that we are trying to "clean up the square brackets and the apostrophes to have a clean list of IDs."

Comment: @Carcigenicate Maybe I didn't phrase my question well, but I don't understand why it would be el[3].strip and why it wouldn't just be el.strip? Since there are varying values in the data set.

Comment: Command `line.split(" +++$+++ ")` from above leaves a list of lists in a form (for your example) of `['u0', 'u2', 'm0', [‘L194’, ‘L195’, ‘L196’, ‘L197’]]` - he's just interested in that sequence of four LXXXs.

Comment: @ipaleka Ohhh ok that makes more sense, also do you know why he or she specifies the 4th element when there are other values in the same file containing 2 LXXXs?

Comment: `['u0', 'u2', 'm0', [‘L194’, ‘L195’, ‘L196’, ‘L197’]] == [el[0], el[1], el[2], el[3]]`

Comment: @ipaleka I understand that it would work in that case but would it throw an error if the line was: u0 +++$+++ u2 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ ['L198', 'L199']? Since it would be [el[0], el[1]]?

Comment: I didn't give an example that works, just the visual example that may help you understand. Lxxxs aren't part of el, they are el[3][0], el[3][1], ...

Comment: @ipaleka Sorry for so many questions but I have one last one. Do you know why in the case of this tutorial one would only want to look up to the 4th element?

Comment: Because those Lxxxs are indexes of spoken lines, and as the texts of those spoken lines aren't placed on the same place, he uses it to extract the actual text from somewhere else.

Comment: @ipaleka I understand that part but there are some that contain 5 or 6 indexes and I'm not sure why you wouldn't want to go through all of them and not just till the 4th?

Comment: He catches EVERY INDEX PROVIDED, no matter there's only one, four or six of them - you just don't comprehend what I wrote.